# Writing Views using Jquery UI widgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Our company is about to start a new web based product on asp.net mvc. We have different clients who require different themes on our application. To make user interface to support different themes, we are thinking to develop our UI completely using JQuery UI widgets (buttons, dropdown and everything using jquery UI). This way we won't have to deal with re-writing CSS for every client. Can you guys please provide me with your feedback, do you think it's a good idea to create UI entirely using jquery UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Use Razor to generate the markup. You shouldn't have to reqrite javascript for each client unless they want different client-side functionality.

Comment: We are not re-writing JS for each client. It's just that every client needs different UI themes. As Jquery UI controls support themes, we are thinking to use it's widgets to create our entire user interface.